# How to get the number of the instance in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Consider the following table:

```
| name | instance |
|------|----------|
| foo  | 1        |
| foo  | 2        |
| bar  | 1        |
| bar  | 2        |
| bar  | 3        |
| baz  | 1        |
| baz  | 2        |
```

What formula should I use to get the `instance` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
=Arrayformula(if(A2:A="",,countifs(A2:A, A2:A, row(A2:A), "<="&row(A2:A))))
```

[image]